Welcome Banner for Users
I have recently created a SharePoint homepage for my company that acts as an intranet point of entry. I would really like to create a welcome banner at the top of the homepage that simply says "Good morning, [user name]." and adjusts throughout the day to reflect the user's time zone.
I've looked into it, and it seems that by using Power Automate and a SharePoint Framework Web Part, I can make this happen (also with a bit of Javascript), but I'm unsure if this is the only/best way, and how to begin, so any input would be welcome!

Webpart is the way to do this. I don't see a reason to use Power Automate. Try this:
<div id="welcomeBanner" style="background-color: #0078d4; color: white; padding: 20px; text-align: center; font-size: 1.5em; border-radius: 5px; margin-bottom: 20px;">
    <p>Welcome to Our SharePoint Site!</p>
    <p>We are glad to have you here. Explore and enjoy your experience!</p>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    // You can customize this script to show different messages based on user roles or other conditions.
    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
        var userName = _spPageContextInfo.userDisplayName;
        var bannerMessage = "Welcome, " + userName + "!";
        
        document.getElementById("welcomeBanner").getElementsByTagName("p")[0].innerText = bannerMessage;
    });
</script>

Another example: https://steveknutson.blog/2023/04/09/how-to-create-an-intranet-welcome-message/
A ready solution for free: https://appsource.microsoft.com/en-nz/product/office/WA200005571?tab=Overview
